# Hide input history dropdown list in Chrome not working

Tags: html

I tried using the `autocomplete = "off"` attribute, but it didn't work in Google Chrome. It still displays the dropdown with the inputs from before. So for example if I enter Google it still displays a dropdown list saying "Google Chrome" and "Google Nexus" that I both entered in the past. So it still displays the AutoComplete list. How can I remove the list?

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem. What happened when you tried it? Did you get incorrect results? If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect? What were you expecting instead? Did you get *any* correct results? If so, what were they? Don't make us guess.

Comment: Make sure your input got a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

try this in javascript

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome')>=0)
{
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('inputid').autocomplete='off';},1);
}
```

**i use it in my website and work!**

Comment: what's your chrome version?